# How to delete a row in table with Django

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django. I am trying to add a delete button to delete the row. However, the output is not what I want because it outputs multiple times because I create a loop to get data for other columns. For this reason, is there a solution the delete button can run outside the loop?

add_stock.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Add Stock</h1>

<form action="{% url 'add_stock' %}" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
  <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Add Stock" aria-label="Search" name="ticker">

  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Add Stock</button>
</form>
<br/>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
      <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Extended Hours</th>
      <th scope="col">Change</th>
      <th scope="col">% Change</th>
      <th scope="col">Volume</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

{% if ticker %}
  
  {% for list_item in output %}
    {% for item in ticker %}
      <tr>
          <th scope="row"> {{ list_item.symbol }} </th>
          <td>{{ list_item.companyName }}</td>
          <td>${{ list_item.latestPrice }}</td>
          <td>${{ list_item.extendedPrice }}</td>
          <td>{{ list_item.change }}</td>
          <td>{{ list_item.changePercent }}%</td>
          <td>{{ list_item.volume }}</td>
          <td><a href=" {% url 'delete' item.id %} "> Delete </a></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}

  
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('about.html', views.about, name='about'),
    path('add_stock.html', views.add_stock, name='add_stock'),
    path('delete/<stock_id>', views.delete, name='delete')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Stock
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import StockForm


def home(request):
import requests
import json

if request.method == 'POST':
    ticker = request.POST['ticker']
        # pk_1c2f5aec07a04049afc7200c61b6b1f3
    api_request = requests.get("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/" + ticker + "/quote?token=pk_1c2f5aec07a04049afc7200c61b6b1f3")

    try:
        api = json.loads(api_request.text)
    except Exception as e:
        api = 'Error...'
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'api': api})

else:
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'ticker': 'Enter a symbol...'})


# return render(request, 'home.html', {'api': api})

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {})

def add_stock(request):
import requests
import json

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = StockForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, ('Stock added'))
        return redirect('add_stock')

else:
    ticker = Stock.objects.all()
    output = []
    for ticker_item in ticker:

        api_request = requests.get("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/" + str(ticker_item) + "/quote?token=pk_1c2f5aec07a04049afc7200c61b6b1f3")

        try:
            api = json.loads(api_request.text)
            output.append(api)
        except Exception as e:
            api = 'Error...'


    return render(request, 'add_stock.html', {'ticker': ticker, 'output': output})

def delete(request, stock_id):
    item = Stock.objects.get(pk=stock_id)
    item.delete()
    messages.success(request, ('Stock has deleted'))
    return redirect(add_stock)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two lists (`ticker` and `output`) I would create a single list of two-tuples such that you only iterate over a single list in your template.

views.py

```
def add_stock(request):
    import requests
    import json

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StockForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Stock added'))
            return redirect('add_stock')

    else:
        ticker = Stock.objects.all()
        items = []
        for ticker_item in ticker:

            api_request = requests.get("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/" + str(ticker_item) + "/quote?token=pk_1c2f5aec07a04049afc7200c61b6b1f3")

            try:
                api = json.loads(api_request.text)
                output.append(api)
            except Exception as e:
                api = 'Error...'
            items.append((ticker, api))


        return render(request, 'add_stock.html', {'items': items})
```

relevant part of add_stock.html:

```
{% for item, list_item in items %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"> {{ list_item.symbol }} </th>
        <td>{{ list_item.companyName }}</td>
        <td>${{ list_item.latestPrice }}</td>
        <td>${{ list_item.extendedPrice }}</td>
        <td>{{ list_item.change }}</td>
        <td>{{ list_item.changePercent }}%</td>
        <td>{{ list_item.volume }}</td>
        <td><a href=" {% url 'delete' item.id %} "> Delete </a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```